# Como alterar localização em PostgreSQL

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql

Meu banco de dados está com *locale* `en_US.UTF-8`, preciso alterá-lo para `pt_BR.UTF-8` por questões de ordenação das consultas.

Como poderei faço isso apenas com **phpPgAdmin**?

Answer (score 4):

Para alterar você terá que:

1. Fazer um backup lógico da sua base atual, talvez tenha essa opção no phpPgAdmin, mas desconheço, via linha de comando seria algo como:

   ```
   $ pg_dump -d nome_da_base -f nome_da_base.sql
   ```
2. Apagar sua base atual:

   ```
   DROP DATABASE nome_da_base;
   ```
3. Recriá-la usando usando o `template0` e o *locale* correto:

   ```
   CREATE DATABASE nome_da_base
       TEMPLATE=template0
       LC_CTYPE="pt_BR.UTF-8"
       LC_COLLATE="pt_BR.UTF-8";
   ```
4. Restaurar:

   ```
   $ psql -d nome_da_base -f nome_da_base.sql
   ```

Se seu banco for muito grande esse processo poderá ser um pouco lento, nesse caso seria melhor usar um backup binário (recomendo `-Fc`, ou `-Fd` para usar paralelismo) e restaurar com o `pg_restore` usando paralelismo.